# Where can we find Qiskit exercises solution/answers?

Tags: qiskit, resource-request

Where can we find Qiskit Exercises solution/answers, is there any website for it?
Or any alternative way to check our answer/solution?

Comment: I found [these](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook/tree/solutions/content/solutions) solutions to chapter 1 and 2 of the QIskit textbook. However, they are still in review and haven't been officialy pushed to the main branch of the repo.

Comment: Thanks @epelaaez, its enough for now.

Comment: As far as I know, Qiskit documentation itself provides exercises throughout its presentation of the theory. Have a look [here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/content/ch-ex/).